# I can't figure out why this cURL request won't work in PHP

Tags: php, curl

**Edit: The issue is that when I use `var_dump()`, it's null.**

Sorry if I do this wrong, I'm new here. What I know:

- The API works with normal cURL (`curl -H "Authorization: [token]" -d "src=google" -d "dest=https://google.com"`)
- `$src`, `$dest`, and `$auth` are set (and correctly).
- When entering an invalid `$auth`, the API returns a 401 (Unauthorized Request), along with all failed requests.
- The API is my own (also built in PHP).

  ```
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://coles.life/api/long/create/");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: '.$auth));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(
      array(
          "src"   => $src,
          "dest"  => $dest
      )
  ));

  $out = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  $res = json_decode($out, true);
  ```

Comment: Whoops, probably should've proofread. I meant "What I know" and "401 (Unauthorized Request)" **Edit**: Edited the post.

Comment: Is this a GET request or POST request? I jumped directly to answering :)

Comment: Check the $auth variable value. and Check for Chrome Developer Tools' request window if the $auth variable is passed correctly.

Comment: @TahaPaksu It's a POST request, and as previously noted, `$auth` is set.

Comment: Then try my answer.

Comment: Are you doing any error checking?  Curl can return status codes for both Curl itself and the HTTP request it just executed.

Comment: Are you checking `$out`, or `$res`? `$out` is the real result, check it before getting `json_decode` involved.

Comment: "along with all unauthorized requests." lolwat? I hope that's sanitized or served with text content-type, else that's "how to make your website vulnerable to XSS 101"

Comment: when debugging curl code, set CURLOPT_VERBOSE, and check STDERR, post the CURLOPT_VERBOSE log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, turns out in the database I had `varchar(255)` set and was trying to pass a value > 255.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

to define that this will be a `POST` request.

Comment: There isn't an error message in the first place, the request value is just NULL.

Comment: You mean response? The 401 is gone then?

Comment: The 401 is only when a 401 is valid, it returns NULL when the request seems like it should work.